# Using AutoMapper to dynamically map objects including arrays

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper

I'm trying to build a way of mapping from one type to another, knwoing they will (should) have the same structure. [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622003/call-webservice-without-adding-a-webreference-with-complex-types).

For ease of the fiddly bits, I'm using AutoMapper from Codeplex, with the following function:

```
private static List<Type> seenTypes = new List<Type>();

private static void MapDataObjects(Type a, Type b)
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(a, b);

    PropertyInfo[] aProps = a.GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo[] bProps = b.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo aProp in aProps)
    {
        if (aProp.PropertyType.Namespace.StartsWith("System") 
             || seenTypes.Contains(aProp.PropertyType))
            continue;

        foreach (PropertyInfo bProp in bProps)
        {
            if (aProp.Name == bProp.Name)
            {
                MapDataObjects(aProp.PropertyType, bProp.PropertyType);
                seenTypes.Add(aProp.PropertyType);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Which appears to work fine when stepping through the code, however calling my Map function gives the following error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 
     Trying to map TDXDataTypes.ClientActivity[] to ClientActivity[].
Using mapping configuration for TDXDataTypes.ClientActivity[] to ClientActivity[]
Destination property: Activities
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown. 
    ---> System.ArgumentException: 
         Type 'ClientActivity[]' does not have a default constructor
```

Comment: probably this could interest you http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution (should have tried harder before asking the question):

```
 if (aProp.Name == bProp.Name)
    {
        if (aProp.PropertyType.IsArray)
        {
            MapDataObjects(aProp.PropertyType.GetElementType(), bProp.PropertyType.GetElementType());
            seenTypes.Add(aProp.PropertyType.GetElementType());
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            MapDataObjects(aProp.PropertyType, bProp.PropertyType);
            seenTypes.Add(aProp.PropertyType);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, you only need to map element types for collections, not the collections themselves.